# PhotoSwipe - Connect images to gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using PhotoSwipe https://photoswipe.com/ for an image gallery. I've implemented all the files and coded the gallery, so when I click on a button, the image gallery opens on the first image. Now I want to connect images to the gallery, so when I click on the image thumbnail, it opens this image in the gallery (just like the example on the website). I just don't manage to get it working since the explanation on the website is pretty complicated.
If anyone is familiar with PhotoSwipe, I'd really appreciate some advice.

Here's the JS code, provided by the website, which only works if the image grid is coded in the same way (code below).

```
var initPhotoSwipeFromDOM = function(gallerySelector) {

    // parse slide data (url, title, size ...) from DOM elements 
    // (children of gallerySelector)
    var parseThumbnailElements = function(el) {
        var thumbElements = el.childNodes,
            numNodes = thumbElements.length,
            items = [],
            figureEl,
            linkEl,
            size,
            item;

        for(var i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {

            figureEl = thumbElements[i]; // <figure> element

            // include only element nodes 
            if(figureEl.nodeType !== 1) {
                continue;
            }

            linkEl = figureEl.children[0]; // <a> element

            size = linkEl.getAttribute('data-size').split('x');

            // create slide object
            item = {
                src: linkEl.getAttribute('href'),
                w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
                h: parseInt(size[1], 10)
            };



            if(figureEl.children.length > 1) {
                // <figcaption> content
                item.title = figureEl.children[1].innerHTML; 
            }

            if(linkEl.children.length > 0) {
                // <img> thumbnail element, retrieving thumbnail url
                item.msrc = linkEl.children[0].getAttribute('src');
            } 

            item.el = figureEl; // save link to element for getThumbBoundsFn
            items.push(item);
        }

        return items;
    };

    // find nearest parent element
    var closest = function closest(el, fn) {
        return el && ( fn(el) ? el : closest(el.parentNode, fn) );
    };

    // triggers when user clicks on thumbnail
    var onThumbnailsClick = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;

        var eTarget = e.target || e.srcElement;

        // find root element of slide
        var clickedListItem = closest(eTarget, function(el) {
            return (el.tagName && el.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'FIGURE');
        });

        if(!clickedListItem) {
            return;
        }

        // find index of clicked item by looping through all child nodes
        // alternatively, you may define index via data- attribute
        var clickedGallery = clickedListItem.parentNode,
            childNodes = clickedListItem.parentNode.childNodes,
            numChildNodes = childNodes.length,
            nodeIndex = 0,
            index;

        for (var i = 0; i < numChildNodes; i++) {
            if(childNodes[i].nodeType !== 1) { 
                continue; 
            }

            if(childNodes[i] === clickedListItem) {
                index = nodeIndex;
                break;
            }
            nodeIndex++;
        }



        if(index >= 0) {
            // open PhotoSwipe if valid index found
            openPhotoSwipe( index, clickedGallery );
        }
        return false;
    };

    // parse picture index and gallery index from URL (#&pid=1&gid=2)
    var photoswipeParseHash = function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1),
        params = {};

        if(hash.length < 5) {
            return params;
        }

        var vars = hash.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
            if(!vars[i]) {
                continue;
            }
            var pair = vars[i].split('=');  
            if(pair.length < 2) {
                continue;
            }           
            params[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        }

        if(params.gid) {
            params.gid = parseInt(params.gid, 10);
        }

        return params;
    };

    var openPhotoSwipe = function(index, galleryElement, disableAnimation, fromURL) {
        var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0],
            gallery,
            options,
            items;

        items = parseThumbnailElements(galleryElement);

        // define options (if needed)
        options = {

            // define gallery index (for URL)
            galleryUID: galleryElement.getAttribute('data-pswp-uid'),

            getThumbBoundsFn: function(index) {
                // See Options -> getThumbBoundsFn section of documentation for more info
                var thumbnail = items[index].el.getElementsByTagName('img')[0], // find thumbnail
                    pageYScroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                    rect = thumbnail.getBoundingClientRect(); 

                return {x:rect.left, y:rect.top + pageYScroll, w:rect.width};
            }

        };

        // PhotoSwipe opened from URL
        if(fromURL) {
            if(options.galleryPIDs) {
                // parse real index when custom PIDs are used 
                // http://photoswipe.com/documentation/faq.html#custom-pid-in-url
                for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                    if(items[j].pid == index) {
                        options.index = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // in URL indexes start from 1
                options.index = parseInt(index, 10) - 1;
            }
        } else {
            options.index = parseInt(index, 10);
        }

        // exit if index not found
        if( isNaN(options.index) ) {
            return;
        }

        if(disableAnimation) {
            options.showAnimationDuration = 0;
        }

        // Pass data to PhotoSwipe and initialize it
        gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
        gallery.init();
    };

    // loop through all gallery elements and bind events
    var galleryElements = document.querySelectorAll( gallerySelector );

    for(var i = 0, l = galleryElements.length; i < l; i++) {
        galleryElements[i].setAttribute('data-pswp-uid', i+1);
        galleryElements[i].onclick = onThumbnailsClick;
    }

    // Parse URL and open gallery if it contains #&pid=3&gid=1
    var hashData = photoswipeParseHash();
    if(hashData.pid && hashData.gid) {
        openPhotoSwipe( hashData.pid ,  galleryElements[ hashData.gid - 1 ], true, true );
    }
};

// execute above function
initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('.my-gallery');
```

This is the code with which it works fine.

```
<div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_a4c2eaa0cd_o.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x1024">
          <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_3c27ff3cd1_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
      </a>
                                          <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption  1</figcaption>
                                          
    </figure>

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a href="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_b.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="964x1024">
          <img src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
      </a>
      <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 2</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

And I need to make this work with my image grid, which is constructed like this:

```
<div class="gallery">
   <div class="container gallery-1" itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a href="link" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="800x1200">
          <img src="imgsrc" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="alt">
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="container gallery-1" itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a href="link" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="800x1200">
          <img src="imgsrc" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="alt">
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS gives me an error at `size = linkEl.getAttribute('data-size').split('x');` that linkEl.getAttribute('data-size') is null although when using `console.log(size = linkEl.getAttribute('data-size').split('x'));` right below it, I get the right console log without any errors.

Here's a working gallery, https://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/ZYbPJM which also works fine on my website. But when using my gallery, it gives me the error stated above.

Comment: Can you post your code please so we could understand the gaps?

Comment: @MoshFeu I added the code.

Comment: First, about the error, what exactly the error? Maybe there is a specific element which doesn't have `data-size` attribute. Second, if you already copied the example's code it doesn't make sense that it throws an error unless something is different. Can you create a working example so I could actually see the error? (It shouldn't be hard and it will save time for both of us)

Comment: @MoshFeu sorry, the error is ```Cannot read property 'split' of null```, which doesn't make any sense since the console.log works just fine. I'll post a link of a working gallery in my thread.

Comment: Try to split the lines e.g. `const dataSize = linkEl.getAttribute('data-size');
if (!dataSize) console.log(linkEl)
size = dataSize.split('x')`

Comment: now ```console.log(linkEl)  ``` gives me the ```<img>``` tag, instead of the ```<a>```. Now it makes sense that ```dataSize```is null. But why is it now targetting the img tag instead of the a tag?

Comment: Maybe you have an image which doesn't wrapped with `a` tag`..